# How to adjust the width and height of Twilio Video?

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I'm using the following code to do the connection with the Twilio video, and I've tried to set the `connectOptions` object to adjust the width and height of the video. However, I can't handle it, it keeps displaying the videoTrack as 1280 x 720, so I would like to ask anything I still need to add?

```
Video.connect(res.data, connectOptions).then(this.roomJoined, error 
=> {
            console.log("error:")
            console.log(error);
            alert('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
        });
```

connectOptions:

[image]

```
{
  video: {
    width: 640,
    height: 320
  }
}
```